# Finding the number of combinations with two conflicting members

Tags: probability-theory, combinations

From a group of 7 men, how many different committees consisting of 3 can be formed if 2 of them refuse to serve on the committee together?

I know that ${7 \choose 3}$ = 35 is the total number of groups without the conflict and that I should subtract the amount of groups that do contain the conflict. However, I have no idea why it's ${2 \choose 2}$${5 \choose 1}$. Sure, that's the right answer, but what do both parts represent *exactly*?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ denote the set of people of two people who refuse to work together and $B$ denote the remaining group of $5$ people.

To form the committee there are two ways :

1.$3$ people are from $B$ only which is $5\choose 3$.

2.$2$ people are from $B$ and one from $A$ which is $5\choose 2$ $ 2\choose 1$

Comment: I don't think so. There are 30 ways to form the committee. That doesn't add up. And makes even less sense to me.

Comment: Look carefully @kote;That does add up ; $5 \choose 3$+$5\choose 2 $$2\choose 1$=$10+10\times 2=30$;It should make you sense now

Answer (score 0):

We divide the 7 people into 2 groups, of 5 people with no problem, and 2 people who don't want to work with each other.

To make a committee that will fail, we need to take both of the people from the 2-group, i.e, $2 \choose 2$

Now, there is only one space left in the committee, and we have 5 possible options, hence we have $5 \choose 1$

Therefore, total number of impossible committees would be ${5\choose 1} {2 \choose 2}$

Comment: I guess I just find this unintuitive. Could you recommend a textbook that would help me wrap my mind around the seemingly arbitrary and magical use of binomial coefficients?